# Problem with HttpServletRequest & Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets

when i tried to get the requested url on some page on myapp.com
i get something like :
http://127.0.0.1:8084/myapp/mypage

and it was expected to be:
http://myapp.com/mypage

i think that this is because Apache acts as a Mediator between the tomcat and the user requests/responses

any ideas guys why such behaviour occurs, and how to fix it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you connecting your Apache to your Java Application server?

If you are using a plain reverse proxy (mod_proxy), what you are getting is what's expected. You won't be able to change that because of reverse proxy's nature.

On the other hand, if you are using AJP (with mod_ajp, or mod_jk) you should be getting http://myapp.com/mypage.

My suggestion is, change to AJP if you are using a plain reverse proxy.

Comment: i used ajp, it gets the url correctly, but the problem is it makes a bad redirection for example: if you want to access the page mypage it goes to http://myapp.com/myapp/mypage but it should go to http://myapp.com/mypage.

Comment: Show me how you do the redirection (in httpd.conf configuration).

Comment: <Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset Off
   Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
   </Proxy> 
   ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp/

Comment: Change it to: `ProxyPass /myapp/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp`

Comment: If you don't want `myapp` to appear in your `URLs` at all, you can configure `TOMCAT` to serve in the root `/` path your application and redirects should also work.

Comment: i can see the apache go to the app but i don know why my app add appname to the url again to be HTTP Status 404 - /appname/appname/dir/page 

it should be /dir/page

Comment: any other ideas, i am run out of ideas, i tried everything, but this stupid problem still there.